# Name value pairs in Grails Views

Tags: grails, grails3

I have a `Header` class like so:

```
class Header {
  String name
  String value
}
```

I have a [Grails View](http://views.grails.org/latest/#_introduction) like this:

```
model {
  Set<Header> headers
}

json {
  headers ....
}
```

I want to produce JSON formatted like this:

```
{
  "headers": {
    "Host": "xyz.com",
    "Other-Header": "da value"
  }
}
```

I tried generating the JSON value by hand, but Grails just put it inside quotes. So that didn't work.

Comment: This is an unusual way to model what you are doing but it can be made to work.  Do you know for sure that the `Set<Header>` will never contain more than 1 `Header` with the same `name` property and if not, what are your requirements for the rendered output with a collision occurs?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown The duplicate header fields is an interesting scenario. My thought was to be *very* simple for implementers to utilize (being able to get a specific value without having to iterate). I think I'll be implementing both my answer below and the "typical" list of header objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the `Set<Header>` to a `Map<String, String>` first:

```
model {
    Set<Header> headers
}

json {
    headers renderHeaders(email.headers)
}

static Map<String, String> renderHeaders(Set<Header> headers) {
    Map<String, String> res = [:]
    for (Header header : headers) {
        res[header.name] = header.value
    }
    return res
}
```